# Sencha Touch 2.0 loading Buttons dynamically from the store

Tags: button, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Does anyone know if it is possible to have multiple buttons which depend of a specific user , and for each user he has a multiple applications ,in his space (im developping an Appviewer for a PAAS) , if i click in a button or image whatever, i will load an application that contains modules (contact , shopping...)

My json file is like this :

```
   {"status":"ok","applications": 
  [{"id":"894","name":"nameApp","user_id":"256","template_id":"1","status":"3",
    "icon":null,"logo":"","publish_status":"0"},

  {"id":"769","name":"mymodel","user_id":"256","template_id":"4","status":"3",
    "icon":null,"logo":"","publish_status":"0"}
```

is there an idea of how to add dynamically  buttons to Carousel..the number depends of the number of id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define xtype for each type of button, including their handlers, etc. Now suppose you have the user record in a var record, when showing the container for the button you could:

```
container.add({
    xtype: 'shopping-button',
    userid: record.get('id')
});
```

Hope it helps-

Comment: i think that u didnt get my idea , for an application it could be contain several modules ,not for each button a module ,i need  to get buttons dynamically , depending of number of id in json file ...and then on the click it shows me all modules that contain like contact page , shopping , news rss ..